# Exit Telnet Through Batch File

Tags: email, batch-file, telnet

I've been asked to write a script in work that will send an email to our support email if an IP stops allowing us access to telnet on port 23. I've got the gist of what I need, but when the IP doesn't deny access, the script opens telnet and I can't get it to close using a command in the batch file.
This is what I've got so far. Sorry if there is already a question which answers this, I haven't been able to find it.

```
@ECHO OFF
set IPADDRESS=1.2.3.4
set INTERVAL=5

telnet %IPADDRESS% 23 
if errorlevel 1 GOTO LOG

:LOG
ECHO %DATE% %TIME% %IPADDRESS% Could Not Be Reached >> failurelog.txt
GOTO MAIL

:MAIL
blat -install smtpserver
blat failurelog.txt -to email -subject "%IPADDRESS% Is Down"
timeout %INTERVAL%
exit
```

Comment: Rather than using `telnet`, you could use `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` in PowerShell.  Example: `powershell "(new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient).connect('%IPADDRESS%',23)" && ( goto :EOF ) || goto LOG`

Comment: You need a scriptable telnet program. Search the Internet and you will find one.